# Output more than one solution using Google's Linear Optimization Service

Tags: google-apps-script, linear-programming

Is it possible to output more than one solution using Google's Linear Optimization Service? I created a toy scheduling problem below.  It outputs the first solution, but I would like to output more than one solution to the problem.  Is that possible?

```
function schedule() {

var numDays = 5;
var numPeople = 6;

var engine = LinearOptimizationService.createEngine();

for (var d=0; d<numDays; d++) {
  for (var p=0; p<numPeople; p++) {
    engine.addVariable("Day"+d+"Person"+p, 0, 1, LinearOptimizationService.VariableType.INTEGER);  
  }
}

//only one person can work per day
for (var d=0; d<numDays; d++) {
  var constraint = engine.addConstraint(1, 1);
  for (var p=0; p<numPeople; p++) {
    constraint.setCoefficient("Day"+d+"Person"+p, 1);
  }
}

//each person can only work once per week at max
for (var p=0; p<numPeople; p++) {
  var constraint = engine.addConstraint(0, 1);
  for (var d=0; d<numDays; d++) {
    constraint.setCoefficient("Day"+d+"Person"+p, 1);
  }
}  

var solution = engine.solve();

if (solution.isValid()) {
  for (var d=0; d<numDays; d++) {
    Logger.log("Day "+ d);
    for (var p=0; p<numPeople; p++) {
      Logger.log(solution.getVariableValue("Day"+d+"Person"+p));
    }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Try running the function again?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  The output is always the same.  You have to change the variables or constraints to get a different solution.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get all the solutions to a problem from a single call.

You could just call the `solve` method after changing some parameters but there is no guarantee that the results will be different. This would be the case only if you problem cannot be solved optimally during the 30 seconds window.

If you'd like to, file a feature request following the instructions at the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  That's interesting because according to this page https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp the Linear Optimization Service uses Glop or SCIP which you can also access through OR-Tools.  Using OR-Tools in Python you can definitely output more than one solution with `solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)`  I'll take a look at filing a feature request.  Thank you.